# Visual Studio Solution Explorer - Script Documents annoyance

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

[image: Example]

While developing with MVC in Visual Studio, a lot of new scripts are added to the Script Documents, this causes the object to expand, draws focus and scrolls up the solution explorer window. This is very, very annoying because it draws your attention away, and some webpages generate a few script files async which literally stops me from using the solution explorer until I stop debugging.

TLDR; script documents object keeps opening and drawing focus, is there any way to remove this or suppress it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way. The issue is also reported to Visual Studio team, but still not fixed, see: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/provide-a-way-to-prevent-the-script-documents-fold/351537